# Updating old stored procedure after changing database structure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, enums, int

I am updating a stored procedure that takes _POST information and saves it to a MySQL database.  The structure of the table has changed;  Some attributes have changed from TINYINT(0,1) to ENUM(Yes/No).

However when I change the procedure to reflect this I get an parse error.  Meaning my new statement is written wrong.  I am not sure how I have done it wrong.

Code here:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS DSSv3_SummaryInfo_insertPostInfo;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE DSSv3_SummaryInfo_insertPostInfo(
     IN InProjectID INT,
     IN InTimeframe VARCHAR(25),
     IN InDateSpent VARCHAR(3000),
     IN InDateSpentDesc VARCHAR(3000),
     IN InQaName INT,
     IN InWhyStoreDesc TEXT,
     IN InChannelTypeDesc TEXT,
     IN InOtherEntitiesDesc TEXT,
     IN InNetworkDiagramDesc TEXT,
     IN InScopingMethods TEXT,
     IN InScopingConfirmationMethods TEXT,
     IN InScopingMethodEvaluation TEXT,
     IN InScopingMethodDocumentation TEXT,
     IN InScopingMethodAccuracy TEXT,
     IN InScopingAssessorName INT,
     IN InEnvironmentPeople TEXT,
     IN InEnvironmentProcesses TEXT,
     IN InEnvironmentTechnologies TEXT,
     IN InEnvironmentLocations TEXT,
     IN InEnvironmentOther TEXT,
     IN InSegmentationUsed ENUM,
     IN InNoSegmentationAssessor INT,
     IN InSegmentationHow TEXT,
     IN InSegmentationTechnologies TEXT,
     IN InSegmentationValidate TEXT,
     IN InSegmentationFunction TEXT,
     IN InSegmentationIntegrity TEXT,
     IN InWithSegmentationAssessor INT,
     IN InCountriesEntityConductsBusiness TEXT,
     IN InWirelessVerify TEXT,
     IN InWirelessImpact TEXT,
     IN InSamplingNotUsedAssessor INT,
     IN InSamplingUsedAssessor INT,
     IN InSamplingRational TEXT,
     IN InSamplingStandardiseControl TEXT,
     IN InSamplingControlValidation TEXT,
     IN InThirdPartyAssessorPadss INT,
     IN InThirdPartyAssessorP2pe INT,
     IN InThirdPartyScopeReduction TEXT,
     IN InThirdPartyComments TEXT,
     IN InSpIsSp TINYINT,
     IN InSpIncludedRequirements VARCHAR(3000),
     IN InSpExcludedRequirements VARCHAR(3000),
     IN InSpAssessor INT,
     IN InSpIpAddr VARCHAR(1500),
     IN InSpCustomerIpAddr VARCHAR(1500),
     IN InQsInitial TINYINT,
     IN InQsAmount TINYINT,
     IN InQsPassAssessor INT,
     IN InQsDocumentAssessor TEXT,
     IN InQsCorrection TEXT,
     IN InQsAssessorComments TEXT,
     IN InQsAocAssessor TEXT
     )
BEGIN
    /*
    set all _POST data for executive summary
    InParam:
            All _POST data variables on executive summary form
            Excludes _FILES data

    */
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SummaryInfo WHERE ProjectID = InProjectID) THEN
        INSERT INTO SummaryInfo(
             ProjectID,
             timeframe,
             date_spent,
             date_spent_desc,
             qa_name,
             why_store_desc,
             channel_type_desc,
             other_entities_desc,
             network_diagram_desc,

             scoping_methods,
             scoping_confirmation_methods,
             scoping_method_evaluation,
             scoping_method_documentation,
             scoping_method_accuracy,
             scoping_assessor_name,

             environment_people,
             environment_processes,
             environment_technologies,
             environment_locations,
             environment_other,

             segmentation_used,
             no_segmentation_assessor,
             segmentation_how,
             segmentation_technologies,
             segmentation_validate,
             segmentation_function,
             segmentation_integrity,
             with_segmentation_assessor,
             countries_entity_conducts_business,
             wireless_verify,
             wireless_impact,

             sampling_not_used_assessor,
             sampling_used_assessor,
             sampling_rational,
             sampling_standardise_control,
             sampling_control_validation,
             third_party_assessor_padss,
             third_party_assessor_p2pe,
             third_party_scope_reduction,
             third_party_comments,

             sp_is_sp,
             sp_included_requirements,
             sp_excluded_requirements,
             sp_assessor,
             sp_ip_addr,
             sp_customer_ip_addr,

             qs_initial,
             qs_amount,
             qs_pass_assessor,
             qs_document_assessor,
             qs_correction,
             qs_assessor_comments,
             qs_aoc_assessor
            ) 
        VALUES (
            InProjectID,
            InTimeframe,
            InDateSpent,
            InDateSpentDesc,
            InQaName,
            InWhyStoreDesc,
            InChannelTypeDesc,
            InOtherEntitiesDesc,
            InNetworkDiagramDesc,

            InScopingMethods,
            InScopingConfirmationMethods,
            InScopingMethodEvaluation,
            InScopingMethodDocumentation,
            InScopingMethodAccuracy,
            InScopingAssessorName,

            InEnvironmentPeople,
            InEnvironmentProcesses,
            InEnvironmentTechnologies,
            InEnvironmentLocations,
            InEnvironmentOther,

            InSegmentationUsed,
            InNoSegmentationAssessor,
            InSegmentationHow,
            InSegmentationTechnologies,
            InSegmentationValidate,
            InSegmentationFunction,
            InSegmentationIntegrity,
            InWithSegmentationAssessor,
            InCountriesEntityConductsBusiness,
            InWirelessVerify,
            InWirelessImpact,

            InSamplingNotUsedAssessor,
            InSamplingUsedAssessor,
            InSamplingRational,
            InSamplingStandardiseControl,
            InSamplingControlValidation,

            InThirdPartyAssessorPadss,
            InThirdPartyAssessorP2pe,
            InThirdPartyScopeReduction,
            InThirdPartyComments,

            InSpIsSp,
            InSpIncludedRequirements,
            InSpExcludedRequirements,
            InSpAssessor,
            InSpIpAddr,
            InSpCustomerIpAddr,

            InQsInitial,
            InQsAmount,
            InQsPassAssessor,
            InQsDocumentAssessor,
            InQsCorrection,
            InQsAssessorComments,
            InQsAocAssessor 
            );
    ELSE 
        UPDATE SummaryInfo SET
            timeframe = InTimeframe,
            date_spent = InDateSpent,
            date_spent_desc = InDateSpentDesc,
            qa_name = InQaName,
            why_store_desc = InWhyStoreDesc,
            channel_type_desc = InChannelTypeDesc,
            other_entities_desc = InOtherEntitiesDesc,
            network_diagram_desc = InNetworkDiagramDesc,

            scoping_methods = InScopingMethods,
            scoping_confirmation_methods = InScopingConfirmationMethods,
            scoping_method_evaluation = InScopingMethodEvaluation,
            scoping_method_documentation = InScopingMethodDocumentation,
            scoping_method_accuracy = InScopingMethodAccuracy,
            scoping_assessor_name = InScopingAssessorName,

            environment_people = InEnvironmentPeople,
            environment_processes = InEnvironmentProcesses,
            environment_technologies = InEnvironmentTechnologies,
            environment_locations = InEnvironmentLocations,
            environment_other = InEnvironmentOther,

            segmentation_used = InSegmentationUsed,
            no_segmentation_assessor = InNoSegmentationAssessor,
            segmentation_how = InSegmentationHow,
            segmentation_technologies = InSegmentationTechnologies,
            segmentation_validate = InSegmentationValidate,
            segmentation_function = InSegmentationFunction,
            segmentation_integrity = InSegmentationIntegrity,
            with_segmentation_assessor = InWithSegmentationAssessor,
            countries_entity_conducts_business = InCountriesEntityConductsBusiness,
            wireless_verify = InWirelessVerify,
            wireless_impact = InWirelessImpact,

            sampling_not_used_assessor = InSamplingNotUsedAssessor,
            sampling_used_assessor = InSamplingUsedAssessor,
            sampling_rational = InSamplingRational,
            sampling_standardise_control = InSamplingStandardiseControl,
            sampling_control_validation = InSamplingControlValidation,

            third_party_assessor_padss = InThirdPartyAssessorPadss,
            third_party_assessor_p2pe = InThirdPartyAssessorP2pe,
            third_party_scope_reduction = InThirdPartyScopeReduction,
            third_party_comments = InThirdPartyComments,

            sp_is_sp = InSpIsSp,
            sp_included_requirements = InSpIncludedRequirements,
            sp_excluded_requirements = InSpExcludedRequirements,
            sp_assessor = InSpAssessor,
            sp_ip_addr = InSpIpAddr,
            sp_customer_ip_addr = InSpCustomerIpAddr,

            qs_initial = InQsInitial,
            qs_amount = InQsAmount,
            qs_pass_assessor = InQsPassAssessor,
            qs_document_assessor = InQsDocumentAssessor,
            qs_correction = InQsCorrection,
            qs_assessor_comments = InQsAssessorComments,
            qs_aoc_assessor = InQsAocAssessor  

        WHERE
            ProjectID = InProjectID;
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Error message:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that    corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN InNoSegmentationAssessor INT,IN InSegmentationH' at line 22

When I change the ENUM back to an INT like it was before the structure change the stored procedure loads without error.  However it of course wont work because it doesn't match the structure of the database.

I have been looking for an answer but I am note sure exactly what I am doing wrong in the first place in this particular instance.  Any hints or suggestions would be good.

Yes it is a massive procedure.  It is legacy code.  Yes it an ENUM.  It is to produce a report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare an `ENUM`, you have to specify the values. So it should be:

```
IN InSegmentationUsed ENUM('Yes', 'No'),
```

Comment: So I have to define the values again?  doesnt the table structure know the value? ('yes', 'no') ?

Comment: The procedure parameters aren't part of the table.

Comment: What you could do instead is declare the procedure parameter as `VARCHAR`. When you use them to insert into the table, the strings will be converted to the `ENUM`.

Comment: Thanks guys it is working.  Which way is 'better'?
using VARCHAR(3) or ENUM.
I would assume ENUM would be the better way as there is no type conversion?